# How edit messages in Discord.js V12 using message ID

Tags: node.js, discord.js

There is the way to edit a message on DiscordJS

Comment: Is there an issue you are trying to solve here?

Comment: No, this is a tutorial. I tried to do this and don't found any solution. So when I found I published it

Comment: Then please edit your question and provide an answer. [See here for info](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, we just need to pass it to the function, the client variable.

```
exports.myNewFunction = async function myNewTestFunction(client)
```

First, in order to edit a message using the Discord.JS API, we will need to find the server's GuildID.

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(`Your Guild ID`);
```

Now, we're going to need to find the channel the message is on. For this, we will use the channel ID

```
const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.id === `Your message Channel` && c.type === 'text');
```

Finally, let's go to the editing part of the message. For this, we will only need to provide the ID of the message that you want to be edited.

```
channel.messages.fetch(`Your Message ID`).then(message => {
                message.edit("New message Text");
            }).catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
            });
```